# File removed from local repository before push, figure in the remote source after i push upstream

Tags: git, bitbucket

I added an image to my project, then i removed it. Git status prove that:

```
deleted:    My Project Repository/My Project Name/back-button.png
```

However, when i push upstream, i surprisely saw the image `back-button.png` in the source. Why did i find it in my remote? and how to remove it? Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove files from the remote repository, you could use this:

```
git rm --cached MyProjectRepository/MyProjectName/back-button.png
```

In my case, I always forget to add some directories to .gitignore before starting a new project, and I end up to fix repositories later :)
I wrote it in my own blog, so hopefully I won't forget:
http://www.cerioli.com/2012/10/06/remove_folders_and_files_from_git/

Answer (score 1):

Do `git add -u` whenever u deleted some files and want to commit them.